# How to dismiss progress dialog from service?

Tags: android, service, dialog

I have an activity and it shows progress dialog when the user starts download
And the download from ftp start in a service

I want to dismiss this progress dialog when the service finishes downloading file

How to dismiss it from service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be to use **`LocalBroadcastManager`** for notifying `Activity` from `Service`.

**Step1:** Send the local broadcast from your service

```
public class MyService extends Service {

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

      // do your operation here(create worker thread for blocking operations)

      sendLocalBroadCast() //call this method as soon as above operations completes
      return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
  }
} 

  private void sendLocalBroadCast() {  

  Intent intent = new Intent("MY_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION");
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

}
```

> Note that the system calls onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) on your service's main thread. A
>   service's main thread is the same thread where UI operations take
>   place for Activities running in the same process. You should always
>   avoid stalling the main thread's event loop. When doing long-running
>   operations, network calls, or heavy disk I/O, you should kick off a
>   new thread, or use AsyncTask

**Step2:** Make your Activity listen to this broadcast

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity{

         BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

           // you can dismiss your progress dialog here. This method will be called when we receive broadcast from service after the service operation is completed

          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //register for listening to "MY_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION" event 


          LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver,
              new IntentFilter("MY_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION"));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
          super.onDestroy();

       // remove the receiver   
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good but how to trigger event to cancel the progress dialog in mainactivity?

Comment: @user12227210 just take your `ProgressDialog` instance and call `dismiss()` on it.

Comment: What is MyReceiver?

Comment: I cant defin MyReceirver

Comment: @user12227210 I have made the changes, it should  work just fine now

Comment: Method onCreatee does not override method from it super class... Note (i change onCreate to onCreatee because there is another onCreate in activity for Mainactivity

Comment: " there is another onCreate in activity for Mainactivity ", yes only inside this onCreate() register the receiver. No need to create other method

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface finishListener which has listen method, implement it in the activity to do whatever you want and pass it to the service constructor from there call listen method

Answer (score 0):

Its simple

```
 alertdialog.dismiss();
```

just put that in the bottom of your install code